# Explain a block of crazy JS code inside Sizzle(the CSS selector engine)

Tags: javascript, regex, sizzle

So, here is the function for pre-filtering "CHILD":

```
function(match){
    if ( match[1] === "nth" ) {
        // parse equations like 'even', 'odd', '5', '2n', '3n+2', '4n-1', '-n+6'
        var test = /(-?)(\d*)n((?:\+|-)?\d*)/.exec(
            match[2] === "even" && "2n" || match[2] === "odd" && "2n+1" ||
            !/\D/.test( match[2] ) && "0n+" + match[2] || match[2]);

        // calculate the numbers (first)n+(last) including if they are negative
        match[2] = (test[1] + (test[2] || 1)) - 0;
        match[3] = test[3] - 0;
    }

    // TODO: Move to normal caching system
    match[0] = done++;

    return match;
}
```

The code is extracted from [line 442-458 of sizzle.js](http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L442).

So, why is the line `var test = ...`, have the exec inputing a boolean? Or is that really a string?

Can someone explain it by splitting it into a few more lines of code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `exec` method will receive a string, because the [Boolean Logical Operators](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.11) can return an operand, and not necessarily a `Boolean` result, for example:

The **Logical AND** operator (`&&`), will return the value of the *second operand* if the first is *truthy*:

```
true && "foo"; // "foo"
```

And it will return the value of the *first operand* if it is by itself *falsy*:

```
NaN && "anything"; // NaN
0 && "anything";   // 0
```

The **Logical OR** operator (`||`) will return the value of the second operand, if the first one is *falsy*:

```
false || "bar"; // "bar"
```

And it will return the value of the *first operand* if it is by itself *non-falsy*:

```
"foo" || "anything"; // "foo"
```

*Falsy* values are: `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `0`, zero-length string, and of course `false`.

Anything else, evaluated in boolean context is *truthy* (will coerce to `true`).

So, let's look the expression:

```
var test = /(-?)(\d*)n((?:\+|-)?\d*)/.exec(
  match[2] === "even" && "2n" ||  // return '2n' if match[2] is 'even'
  match[2] === "odd" && "2n+1" || // return '2n+1' if it's 'odd'
  !/\D/.test(match[2]) && "0n+" + match[2]|| // return '0n+N' if it's a digit(N) 
  match[2]  // otherwise, return the match[2] value
 );
```

Comment: IMO this case is an egregiously unreadable abuse of the logical operators. To keep the size down, jQuery is deliberately written excessively tersely (by most good-practices standards), but there is no reason here to use `&&`...`||` over the more explicit `?`...`:`.

Comment: @bobnice: I agree with you, I don't quite like how they use the logical operators in this snippet, but I'm not sure *why* they did it in this way, since the ternary operator would actually *save 6 characters*... any thoughts ?